# ng-click ou alternativa em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Preciso que, ao clicar na imagem thumb, escreva a imagem clicada na div .currentImage

> Script

```
    .directive('galeria',function() {
return {
    templateUrl:'scripts/directives/galeria/galeria.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
        'pasta':'@',
        'restrito':'@',
    },
    controller: function($scope,$http){
        // INICIAR CAROUSEL DA HOME 
        $(".thumbsGaleria").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay:true,
            jsonPath: "api/galeria.php?id="+$scope.pasta,
            jsonSuccess: customDataSucesso,
            afterAction: afterFunction
        })
        function customDataSucesso(data){
            var content = "";
            for(var i in data){
                   var img = data[i];
                content += '<img src="painel/modulos/galerias/pastas/'+$scope.pasta+'/'+img+'" ng-click="currentClick('+img+')" style="width:100%; padding-right:10px; max-height:415px">'
             }
            $(".thumbsGaleria").html(content);
        }
        // FIM CAROUSEL

        function afterFunction(elem){
            var current = this.currentItem;
            var src = elem.find(".owl-item").eq(current).find("img").attr('src');
            $(".currentImage").html("<img src='"+src+"' >");
        }

        $scope.currentClick = function(imgCurrent){
            $(".currentImage").html("<img src='"+imgCurrent+"' >");
        }

    }
}  });
```

> HTML

```
<section class="section box" >
<div class="thumbsGaleria"></div>

<div class="currentImage">
</div>
```

Porém o NG-CLICK não funciona, ao clicar no item, não acontece nada.
tentei colocar um ONCLICK ao clicar o console retorna que a função especificada não existe.

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Onde está o ng-click?

Comment: Alí na função customDataSucesso(data)
na var content

Comment: A sim, não havia notado.. Se você der um 'Inspect' no elemento depois da  página ter sido carregada, o ngClick aparece no elemento?

Comment: sim, aparece. porém, ao clicar não executa a função.

Comment: Acho que você não está passando o destino correto dentro do ngClick ou não está propagando a mudança. Verifique pelo inspect qual o src que é atribuído ao "currentImg" após o clique. Se houver alteração no src, verifique se está no destino correto

Comment: A questão não é que não está executando a função ao clicar no item com ng-click ...

Comment: @WilsonLavrador Quando você acha uma solução, coloque como resposta e aceite ela. Não coloque a resposta como parte da pergunta. Veja o [tour].

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA SOLUCIONADO**

substitui a $scope.currentClick pelo script abaixo.

```
        $(".thumbsGaleria").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
            var imagem = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
            $(".currentImage").html("<img src='"+imagem+"' >");
        });
```

Obrigado aos que deram atenção.